# Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY' in JPA/Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have a `many-to-many` relation in a mysql database (`Module - <Module_has_Subject> - Subject`). Entites were generated by Eclipse, I added the method `add` in both classes. I use JBoss AS7/Hibernate. When I call the `persist` method in EJB, I get

```
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '3' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I know it must be a trivial mistake, but I just don't see it. I went through most related problems here on StackOverflow and RoseIndia (I added `cascade`, `targetEntity`,...) and still without success. Entities for tables are as such:

Module.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Module")
public class Module implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
private int idModule;

//bi-directional many-to-many association to Subject
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="modules", fetch=FetchType.EAGER,targetEntity=entity.Subject.class,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Subject> subjects;

public void addSubject(Subject subject) {
    if(subject.getModules() == null) {
        subject.setModules(new ArrayList<Module>());
    }
    if(getSubjects() == null) {
        setSubjects(new ArrayList<Subject>());
    }
    if (!getSubjects().contains(subject)) {
        getSubjects().add(subject);
    }
    if (!subject.getModules().contains(this)) {
        subject.getModules().add(this);
    }
}
...}
```

Subject.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Subject")
public class Subject implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    private int idSubject;

    //bi-directional many-to-many association to Module
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity=entity.Module.class,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
        name="Module_has_Subject"
        , joinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="Subject_idSubject", nullable=false, referencedColumnName="idSubject")
            }
        , inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="Module_idModule", nullable=false, referencedColumnName="idModule")
            }
        )
    private List<Module> modules;

    public void addModule(Module module) {
        if(getModules() == null) {
            setModules(new ArrayList<Module>());
        }
        if(module.getSubjects() == null) {
            module.setSubjects(new ArrayList<Subject>());
        }

        if (!getModules().contains(module)) {
            getModules().add(module);
        }
        if (!module.getSubjects().contains(this)) {
            module.getSubjects().add(this);
        }
    }
    ...}
```

SubjectEJB.java

```
...
Subject subject = new Subject();
for(Module module : subjectModules) {
  subject.addModule(module);
}
em.persist(subject);
em.flush();
...
```

Comment: are you persisting the data twice?

Comment: I hope not:P. I made everything by existing code for bidirectional mapping(http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JPA/ManyToManyBidirectionalMapping.htm). That are methods addModule and addSubject. As I understand, it is up to developer to take care of making all entities and references to them, before they are persisted. In this case, for example when you assign Modules to Subject(or vice versa) you also have to make references in Module entities back to Subject object. And if Module is already persisted, you still have to give him reference to Subject, that is in relation to him, right?

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if you managed to solve your problem yet, but I have just had exactly the same problem.

In my `@OneToMany` mapping I used `CascadeType.ALL` which resulted in 2 records being saved when I attempted to save the entity. (duplicated data, different ID's)

After scrolling on the web, I found this http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?t=511992, so I changed from `CascadeType.ALL` to `{CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}`, which caused the error you have:

```
"ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '9-2-2012-05-30' for key 'PlayerId'"
```

Finally I removed `CascadeType.MERGE` and was left with `CascadeType.PERSIST` which fixed the duplicate entry error and the duplicated records.

As a point, if I use just `CascadeType.MERGE` or just `CascadeType.PERSIST`, I get no errors and no duplicated data

Maybe try with `CascadeType.MERGE`and `CascadeType.PERSIST`, if you get errors, try with just `CascadeType.MERGE`.

It is not ideal, but hope it helps.

Chris