# Java Hibernate Duplicate entry error on merge

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using `Java 8` with `Spring 4.3.1.RELEASE` and `Hibernate 5.2.1.Final` and `JPA` with `MySQL`.

I have a row in the database:

**PERSON TABLE**

```
# ID, UID, JOINING_DATE, LASTACCESS_DATE, DISPLAY_NAME, EMAIL_ADDRESS, AVATAR, PROVIDER, AVATAR_FIREBASE, MILES_KM, NOTIFICATIONS, CONTACTABLE, DEVICE_TOKEN
'384', 'h6qQg5YfQveTaCyBEXwDMSJPqwk1', '1499148701258', '1499240111170', 'Richard', 'richardmarais@gmail.com', ?, '3', 'https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p100x100/14484731_10155363658503146_8505143722410369457_n.jpg?oh=3b6fbb0facc9457f7e8387e4853278a8&oe=59D6034D', '0', '1', NULL, 'e_6U3WAVHu0:APA91bFibmAaVTLO13vG1Aww0yLK2UzRNopLK1UalurfYRXcCbUDrTJQKOm0hiKkyxV1auEWTL9od5ek62FfJIzo1li6vrgA6CfxE6Cu2HnPkSPGaeFispI2c16UBZcLZfYGRe1i9nmf'
```

When I try use Hibernate to `merge` an object with the existing row, it throws an error that it's a duplicate. I thought because I am doing a `merge`, it would UPDATE the existing row.

I have the following code:

**PersonServiceImpl.java**

```
@Transactional
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService {

    @Override
    public Person save(Person person) throws Exception {
        try {
            person = personDao.merge(person);
```

which calls:

**PersonDaoImpl.java**

```
public class PersonDaoImpl extends JpaDao<Long, Person> implements PersonDao

    @Override
    public Person merge(Person person) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        Person foundPerson = null;
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(person.getUid())) {
            foundPerson = findByUid(person.getUid(), person.getProvider());
        }
        if (foundPerson == null && !StringUtils.isEmpty(person.getId())) {
            foundPerson = findById(person.getId());         
        }
        if ((foundPerson == null || foundPerson.getUid() == null) && person.getEmailAddress() != null) {
            foundPerson = findByEmail(person.getEmailAddress());
            if (foundPerson != null) {
                foundPerson.setUid(person.getUid());
            }
        }

        if (foundPerson != null && person.getUid().equals(foundPerson.getUid())) {
            if (person.getLocations().isEmpty() && foundPerson.getLocations() != null && !foundPerson.getLocations().isEmpty()) {
                person.setLocations(foundPerson.getLocations());
            }

            BeanUtils.copyProperties(person, foundPerson);

            if (foundPerson.getLocations().isEmpty() && person.getLocations() != null && !person.getLocations().isEmpty()) {
                foundPerson.setLocations(person.getLocations());
            }
            foundPerson.setLastAccessDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
            if (Objects.isNull(foundPerson.getJoiningDate()) || foundPerson.getJoiningDate() == 0) {
                foundPerson.setJoiningDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
            }           
            return super.merge(foundPerson);   // << line executed
        } else {
            return super.merge(person);
        }
    }
```

which calls:

**JpaDao.java**

```
public class JpaDao<I, T extends AbstractDomain<I>> {

    protected Class<T> entityClass;

    protected T merge(T entity) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        T attached = null;
        if (entity.getId() != null) {
            attached = entityManager.find(entityClass, entity.getId());  // << line executed
        }
        if (attached == null) {
            attached = entityClass.newInstance();
        }

        BeanUtils.copyProperties(entity, attached);
        entityManager.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);
         attached = entityManager.merge(attached);

        return attached;
    }
```

However, when I try `merge` the `Person` object, I get the following error:

**Error**

> 09:53:10,775 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper]
>   (default task-33) SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000 09:53:10,781 ERROR
>   [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-33)
>   Duplicate entry '384-8576' for key 'PRIMARY' 09:53:10,781 INFO 
>   [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl] (default
>   task-33) HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC
>   statements 09:53:10,782 ERROR
>   [org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl] (default task-33)
>   HHH000346: Error during managed flush
>   [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement]

**Question**

How would I implement the code in order to allow UPDATES if the row exists?

Thank you

**More info**

Here is the `Entity` concerned:

**Person.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@XmlRootElement(name = "person")
public class Person extends AbstractDomain<Long> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "UID")
    private String uid;

    @Column(name = "JOINING_DATE", nullable = false)
    private Long joiningDate;

    @Column(name = "LASTACCESS_DATE", nullable = false)
    private Long lastAccessDate;

    @Size(min = 1, max = 85)
    @Column(name = "DISPLAY_NAME", nullable = false)
    private String displayName;

    @Size(min = 5, max = 55)
    @Column(name = "EMAIL_ADDRESS", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String emailAddress;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "person_language", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "PER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "LANG_ID", referencedColumnName = "LANGUAGE_CODE", unique = true) })
    private Set<Language> languages;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinTable(name = "person_location", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "PER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "LOC_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", unique = true) })
    private Set<LocationPerson> locations = null;

    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "AVATAR", nullable = true)
    private byte[] avatar;

    @Column(name = "PROVIDER")
    private Integer provider;

    @Column(name = "AVATAR_FIREBASE")
    private String avatarFirebase;

    @Column(name = "MILES_KM")
    private Integer milesKm;

    @Column(name = "NOTIFICATIONS")
    private Integer notifications;

    @Size(max = 256)
    @Column(name = "DEVICE_TOKEN")
    private String deviceToken;

    @XmlElement
    public String getDeviceToken() {
        return deviceToken;
    }

    public void setDeviceToken(String deviceToken) {
        this.deviceToken = deviceToken;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public Integer getMilesKm() {
        return milesKm;
    }

    public void setMilesKm(Integer milesKm) {
        this.milesKm = milesKm;
    }

    @Column(name = "CONTACTABLE")
    private Long contactable;

    @Transient
    private Boolean contactableFree;

    @XmlElement
    public Boolean getContactableFree() {
        return contactableFree;
    }

    public void setContactableFree(Boolean contactableFree) {
        this.contactableFree = contactableFree;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public Long getContactable() {
        return contactable;
    }

    public void setContactable(Long contactable) {
        this.contactable = contactable;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public Integer getNotifications() {
        return notifications;
    }

    public void setNotifications(Integer notifications) {
        this.notifications = notifications;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public Long getJoiningDate() {
        return joiningDate;
    }

    public void setJoiningDate(Long joiningDate) {
        this.joiningDate = joiningDate;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public Long getLastAccessDate() {
        return lastAccessDate;
    }

    public void setLastAccessDate(Long lastAccessDate) {
        this.lastAccessDate = lastAccessDate;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }

    public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public Set<Language> getLanguages() {
        return languages;
    }

    public void setLanguages(Set<Language> languages) {
        this.languages = languages;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public Set<LocationPerson> getLocations() {
        return locations;
    }

    public void setLocations(Set<LocationPerson> locations) {
        if (this.locations == null) {
            this.locations = locations;
        } else {
            this.locations.retainAll(locations);
            this.locations.addAll(locations);
        }
    }

    public void putLocations(Set<LocationPerson> locations) {
        if (locations != null) {
            this.locations.clear();
            this.locations.addAll(locations);
        } else {
            this.locations = locations;
        }
    }

    @XmlElement
    public byte[] getAvatar() {
        return avatar;
    }

    public void setAvatar(byte[] avatar) {
        this.avatar = avatar;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public Integer getProvider() {
        return provider;
    }

    public void setProvider(Integer provider) {
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getAvatarFirebase() {
        return avatarFirebase;
    }

    public void setAvatarFirebase(String avatarFirebase) {
        this.avatarFirebase = avatarFirebase;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

After reading [the following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380706/duplicate-entry-for-key-primary-in-jpa-hibernate), I change the `Person` object `locations` from `CascadeType.ALL` to `CascadeType.PERSIST`.

**Person.java**

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinTable(name = "person_location", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "PER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "LOC_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", unique = true) })
private Set<LocationPerson> locations = null;
```

The update is done to the database, but I now get the following:

> 10:41:20,657 ERROR
>   [org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl] (default task-7)
>   HHH000346: Error during managed flush
>   [org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved
>   transient instance - save the transient instance beforeQuery flushing:
>   com.jobs.spring.domain.LocationPerson] 10:41:21,429 INFO 
>   [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl] (default
>   task-7) HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC
>   statements

Comment: It does a `merge` on `foundPerson`.  I think it may be related to the `CascadeType.ALL` on the `locations` field, after reading the following. I will just test.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380706/duplicate-entry-for-key-primary-in-jpa-hibernate

Comment: not the solution, but 1-2 hints: 1. You do `BeanUtils.copyProperties()` twice! ..and `person.setUid(foundPerson.getUid())` performs better with the same/desired result. 2. Implement `equals()`and `hashCode()` methods in `Person` (based on uid).

Comment: ...the  `Duplicate entry` (error) comes NOT from Person! ..the `TransientObjectException`..is clear!

Comment: @xerx593, thanks, will give that a try. With regards to the `locations` field on `Person`, should I leave it as `CascadeType.ALL`?

Comment: Yes, the duplicate entry is on `locations` (`LocationPerson`).

Comment: ..yes, `CasacadeType.ALL` or `MERGE` seems more appropriate (pls test)

Comment: After setting it back to `CasacadeType.ALL` and implementing the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods for `uid` on `Person`, I still get the original error.

Comment: `foundPerson.setUid(person.getUid());` never gets executed because the `foundPerson` already has a `uid`.

Comment: nono, sorry you mixed up: `person.setUid(...)` not `foundPerson.setUid(...)`

Comment: Sorry  xerx593, I don't understand what you mean by? `person.setUid(...) not foundPerson.setUid(...)`